# visual studio выдаёт предупреждение: переменная не инициализирована, всегда инициализируйте переменную-член

Tags: visual-studio

Недавно перешёл с Си на плюсы и пока не освоился с синтаксисом, инициализировал поля при объявлении но всё равно ругается
Предупреждения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Matrix.h

```
#pragma once
class Matrix
{
private:
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    int** matrix = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix(int _n, int _m);
    Matrix(int** _matrix, int _n, int _m);
    Matrix(Matrix& _matrix);

    static void freeMatrix(int** _matrix, int _n, int _m);
    static int** mallocMatrix(int _n, int _m);

    void input();
    void output();

    void setValue(int i, int j, int value);
    int getValue(int i, int j);

    void addColumn(int ind);
    void addRow(int ind);

    void deleteColumn(int ind);
    void deleteRow(int num);

    int indMin();
    int indMinInRow(int i);
    int indMinInColumn(int j);

    int indMax();
    int indMaxInRow(int i);
    int indMaxInColumn(int j);

    void resetRowColumnMin();
    void flip1stAndOdd();

    ~Matrix();
};
```

Matrix.cpp:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void Matrix::freeMatrix(int ** _matrix, int _n, int _m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) delete[] _matrix[i];
    delete[] _matrix;
}

int** Matrix::mallocMatrix(int _n, int _m)
{
    int** buf = new int* [_n];
    for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) buf[i] = new int[_m];
    return buf;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int _n, int _m)
{
    n = _n;
    m = _m;
    matrix = mallocMatrix(n, m);
}

Matrix::Matrix(int** _matrix, int _n, int _m)
{
    n = _n;
    m = _m;
    matrix = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = _matrix[i][j];
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(Matrix& _matrix)
{
    n, m = _matrix.n,_matrix.m;
    matrix = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = _matrix.getValue(i,j);
    }
}
```